# table association not created One-To-Many sequelize node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I was creating associations for my database. But she did not create all the associations, for example, she did not link the contracts with the payroll. I tried the options from the database, but they did not help. Tell me what I can try to do and what I'm doing wrong?

Create association

```
db.Contracts.hasMany(db.Payrolls, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'contract_id',
            sourceKey: 'id',
        }
    })
    db.Payrolls.belongsTo(db.Contracts, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'contract_id',
            targetKey: 'id',
        }
    })
```

Create Contracts

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Contracts = sequelize.define("Contracts", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: false
        },
        month_pay: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, { timestamps: false });
    
    return Contracts;
};
```

Create Payrolls

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Payrolls = sequelize.define("Payrolls", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        pay_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        amount: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, { timestamps: false });

    return Payrolls
};
```

[App: DbShema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r73vx.png)

e.g. working associations:

```
module.exports = (db) => {

    //#region One-To-Many Contracts->Courses
    db.Courses.hasMany(db.Contracts, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'course_name',
            sourceKey: 'name',
            primaryKey: true,
        }
    })
    db.Contracts.belongsTo(db.Courses, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'course_name',
            targetKey: 'name',
            primaryKey: true,
        }
    })
    //#endregion

    //#region One-To-Many Contracts->Pupils
    db.Pupils.hasMany(db.Contracts, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'pupil_id',
            sourceKey: 'id',
            primaryKey: true,
        }
    })
    db.Contracts.belongsTo(db.Pupils, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'pupil_id',
            targetKey: 'id',
            primaryKey: true,
        }
    })
    //#endregion
    
    //#region One-To-Many Payrolls->Contracts
    db.Contracts.hasMany(db.Payrolls, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'contract_id',
            sourceKey: 'id',
            
        }
    })
    db.Payrolls.belongsTo(db.Contracts, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'contract_id',
            targetKey: 'id',
            
        }
    })
    //#endregion
    
    return db
}
```

[Visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh9mM.png)

###### [if you need the project itself (its part of the database)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_s5u6MW8xfhct3kayk3RKlqxCyZ9GuCo?usp=sharing)

Comment: How do you create DB structure?

Comment: with sequelize.define, but i tried to do with classes, also
in main file i use sequelize.sync

Comment: Make sure that all associations are registered prior to calling `sync`.

Comment: other associations work correctly in the same file where I make the association from the example

Comment: for example, in the picture that I inserted into the link at the end, the association contract worked correctly: ```pupil_id```; ```course_name```;

Comment: Then show associations that works just as expected as well to see the difference. By th way there is no need to indicate `sourceKey` and `tarjetKey` if they point to a primary key column

Comment: I completed my post with the label "Working associations" and inserted a visualization
Regarding ```targetKey``` and ```sourceKey```, I added them just for clarity, since they do not affect the association itself in any way

Comment: I also added the project archive to Google Drive on the last line.
The effect of the work has not changed (for me at least).

Comment: I looked at the project and didn't find any calls of `sync`

Comment: ```sequelize.sync({alter: false, force: true}).then(async () => ...)```
In file ```index.js```. Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, now I see it. Ok, did you try to create a DB structure from scratch? Just to make sure

Comment: Yes, I created from scratch, all tables are described in the models folder. The associations are in the createAssociations file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incompatible primary key types in `Contracts` and `Payrolls`:
**Contracts**

```js
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: false
        },
```

**Payrolls**

```js
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
```

So DB throws the error that you didn't catch. Add `.catch` to look at it:

```js
sequelize.sync({alter: false, force: true}).then(async () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    })
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
})
```

Also you need to fix other associations that uses `Contacts` to exclude fields other than `id` from a primary key

Comment: I removed the ```primaryKey: true``` fields from the ```Groups``` and ```Attendance``` tables and that solved my problem, but I don't know how to create unique field pairs in the ```Contracts``` and ```Attendance``` table at the database level

Comment: Depens on how you want to link them, i.e. 1:N, N:1, N:M. But that's for another question I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Sequelize v7 documentation for hasMany and belongsTo

https://sequelize.org/api/v7/classes/model#hasMany

https://sequelize.org/api/v7/classes/model#belongsTo

It appears that those sourceKey and targetKey properties that you're passing into the foreignKey objects should be their own properties in the options objects, rather than nested inside of foreignKey.

Comment: You're right, if I have foreign primary keys in the table I'm trying to retrieve its own primary key from, then it won't create an association even if the key I'm trying to retrieve is not a foreign key. But is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say. It sounds like you may be overthinking this, though. To me, it looks like a syntax issue. The sourceKey and targetKey properties that you have as CHILD properties of the foreignKey object should instead be SIBLING properties of foreignKey.